# Colon versus brackets in haskell list syntax

Tags: list, haskell, syntax

I'm currently learning haskell then I came to this exercise where I have to define a function that gets the product of a list of numbers. I was provided with choices and since I am new to haskell there are some notations that I am a bit unclear of.

So I saw this definition on one of the choices:

```
p [x, xs] = x * product xs
```

I can understand this quite a bit, it means to get the product of the list and then multiply it with the value of x.

Then I saw this other definition on one of the other choice:

```
p (x : xs) = x * product xs
```

Which I totally do not understand. It uses parenthesis and a colon which I am having a hard time looking for their definition. I appreciate if someone could enlighten me with regards the syntax and semantics.

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that the syntax `[x, y, z]` is "syntactic sugar" for `x : y : z : []`.  In fact, the definition for lists looks very much like `data [] a = [] | a : ([] a)`.  The `:` is a constructor for the data type `[a]`, and you're just pattern matching on the constructor.  Because we're programmers and like writing lists like `[1, 2, 3]` instead of `1 : 2 : 3 : []`, the compiler has special rules to turn the former into the latter.  Keep this in mind when you see patterns of the form `(x : xs)`.

Comment: That first example really doesn't look like it should type-check...

Comment: @ myself : no, it probably type-checks because somebody could write `instance Num []`...

Answer (score 5):

`[x, xs]` is a list containing two elements. The first element is called `x` and the second is called `xs`. So in this case `product xs` does not calculate the product of the list, it calculates the product of the second element. Since the elements of the list can't be lists themselves (or else multiplying with x wouldn't work), this is a type error.

`x : xs` is a list that contains at least one element. Its first element is called `x` and the list containing its remaining elements is called `xs`.

Answer (score 4):

`:` is the cons operator, which appends an element to a list

`(x : xs)` is pattern-matching a list into an element `x` and the rest of the list `xs`

let's get a concrete example:

```
l = [1,2,3]

show_rest_of_list (x:xs) = xs

show_rest_of_list l
-- would return [2,3]

play_with_list (x:xs) = x : x : xs

play_with_list l
-- would return [1,1,2,3]
```

Comment: Interesting, the example makes me understand better. I gotta try this out in my ghci