# What does the use of a colon between symbols in a parameter in a Haskell function definition do?

Tags: haskell, recursion, pattern-matching, operators

I've been reading through [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/) and I've come across an interesting solution to an exercise in chapter 2.

The exercise asks the reader to construct a function that behaves similarly to Haskell's `drop`.  One [solution](http://haskell.elkstein.org/2009/04/solutions-for-chapter-2.html) looks like this:

```
lastButOne :: [a] -> a
lastButOne (x:xs) = if length xs == 1
                    then x
                    else lastButOne xs
```

With an improved version looking like this:

```
lastButOne :: [a] -> a
lastButOne (x1:[x2]) = x1
lastButOne (x:xs) = lastButOne xs
```

I'm having quite a bit of trouble understanding what the infix colon is doing here.  Can somebody give me an idea of how I should be reading this?

From what I understand, `elem:[b]` tells Haskell to prepend `elem` to `[b]`.

**But** let's suppose I define a function like `lastButOne (x:xs)`.  Then let's suppose I have a list `testCase = [p,q..r]`.  Would I be right in presuming that `lastButOne` would treat `testCase` as two separate objects, i.e. `[p]` and `[q..r]`?

**If** that's the case, the reading the first iteration of `lastButOne` feels totally intuitive.  But then I *still* don't understand how the second iteration of `lastButOne` works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell Confusing Syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407535/haskell-confusing-syntax)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lastButOne (x:xs)...` has only **one** parameter, as you can see from the function's type. The `(x:xs)` is a pattern which matches a list with at least one element. The first element is named `x` and the rest of the list is named `xs`.

Answer (score 0):

**LIGHTBULB.**

```
lastButOne :: [a] -> a
lastButOne (x1:[x2]) = x1
lastButOne (x:xs) = lastButOne xs
```

This code works like so:  Haskell checks the pattern `(x1:[x2])` against the object passed to `lastButOne`.  `(x1:[x2])` is a pattern matching a singleton list prepended by an item of the same type as `x2`.  A list like this `[1,2]` fits this pattern and could be written as `1:[2]`, while a list like this `[1,2,3]` does *not* fit the pattern.  Since the first pattern match fails, Haskell falls through to the 'catch-all' pattern, `x:xs`.

Answer (score 0):

The `:` operator is commonly referred to as `cons` (adopted from Lisp parlance).  `(x:xs)` is a common Haskell pattern match, where `(x:xs)` is an `[a]`, `x` is the head / first element of the list (an `a`), and `xs` is the tail / rest of the list (an `[a]` or list of `a`s).

```
Prelude> let a = (1:2:3:[])
Prelude> let b = (1:[2,3])
Prelude> a
[1,2,3]
Prelude> b
[1,2,3]
```