# Haskell: Syntax for manipulating a list of lists

Tags: list, haskell

I am having trouble finding the correct syntax for manipulating a list of lists.

Here's what I have

```
> sumLsts :: [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
> sumLsts [[]] [[]] = [[]]
> sumLsts [(x:xs):tx] [(y:ys):ty] = [((+) x y) : sumLsts xs ys] : sumLsts tx ty
```

Here's sample input and output

```
> sumLsts [[1,1,1], [1,10,20], [-3, -4, -2]] [[3,5,6],[2,3,4],[2,3,2]]
> [[4,6,7],[3,13,24],[-1,-1,0]]
```

I was thinking that [(x:xs):tx] would have (x:xs) be seen as a single list and tx be seen as the following list. Haskell doesn't seem to agree.

Here is the error message

```
Couldn't match expected type 'a' with actual type '[[a0]]'
'a' is a rigid type variable bound by
   the type signature for:
      sumLsts :: forall a. [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
In the pattern: x : xs
In the pattern: (x : xs) : tx
In the pattern [(x : xs) : tx]
Relevant bindings include
   sumLsts :: [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Colon versus brackets in haskell list syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407535/colon-versus-brackets-in-haskell-list-syntax)

Comment: For some strange reason people always seem to think you need square brackets to pattern-match on any list. You don't!  `[foo]` is specifically a pattern that matches lists with _exactly one element_, no matter if `foo` itself is another pattern. To pop off the head (i.e. in this case, the first row of the 2D list) of _any_ nonzero list, just write `((x:xs):tx)`.

Comment: `[[]]` is not an empty list of type `[[a]]`; it's a list *containing* an empty list. `[]` is the unique empty list for types `[a]`, `[[a]]`, `[[[a]]]`, etc., no matter how deeply nested the type may be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is pointed out in the comments on the question, `(x:xs)` is the pattern for an object of type `[a]`, whether the `a` there is `Int`, `String`, `Bool`, or even `[a]` itself like `[Int]`.

In this case your pattern match should be:

```
sumLsts ((x:xs):tx) ((y:ys):ty) = ...
{- to [[1, 3, 6], [2, 4, 7], [3, 5, 8]], ((x:xs): tx) matches:
   x  = 1
   xs = [3, 6]
   tx = [[2, 4, 7], [3, 5, 8]]
-}
```

However do note that your function is just:

```
sumLsts = zipWith (zipWith (+))
```

`zipWith` pairs two lists together with a joining function, such that

```
zipWith f [x1, x2, ..., xn] [y1, y2, ..., yn] =
  [ f x1 y1
  , f x2 y2
  , ...
  , f xn yn ]
```

In this case, your outer two lists get paired together so each sublist is an `x` and `y`. You're trying to pair *those* together with addition, so `f` is another `zipWith`, this time `zipWith (+)`

```
zipWith (zipWith (+)) [[1,1,1], [1,10,20], [-3, -4, -2]] [[3,5,6],[2,3,4],[2,3,2]]

= [ [ 1,  1,  1] `zipWith (+)` [3, 5, 6]
  , [ 1, 10, 20] `zipWith (+)` [2, 3, 4]
  , [-3, -4, -2] `zipWith (+)` [2, 3, 2]]

= [ [  1 + 3
    ,  1 + 5
    ,  1 + 6]
  , [  1 + 2
    , 10 + 3
    , 20 + 4]
  , [ -3 + 2
    , -4 + 3
    , -2 + 2] ]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thank you! Also a really clear explanation of the syntax, so double thanks!